# Invalid column name on HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have this query :

```
SELECT TOP 100 * ,(3960 * ACOS(cos(radians(39.6128751)) * 
  COS(radians(Lat)) * COS(radians(Lng) - radians(-84.2489525)) + 
  SIN(radians(39.6128751)) * sin(radians(Lat)))) AS Distance
  FROM [Table]  
  HAVING Distance < 50
  ORDER BY Distance DESC
```

The query is to show with the distance of less than 50. But I get an invalid column name 'Distance' on the HAVING statement. Sorry I'm new SQL.

Comment: You can't reference a derived column by name in the having clause within the same query it is created in.

Comment: You cant use a column alias in a having clause. Either repeat the aliased column definition, or DRY it all up with a derived table or cte.

Comment: Oh that's good to know then.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 * ,(3960 * ACOS(cos(radians(39.6128751)) * 
  COS(radians(Lat)) * COS(radians(Lng) - radians(-84.2489525)) + 
  SIN(radians(39.6128751)) * sin(radians(Lat)))) AS Distance
  FROM [Table]  
  HAVING (3960 * ACOS(cos(radians(39.6128751)) * 
  COS(radians(Lat)) * COS(radians(Lng) - radians(-84.2489525)) + 
  SIN(radians(39.6128751)) * sin(radians(Lat)))) < 50
  ORDER BY Distance DESC
```

Comment: That isn't valid. Would need to be 'where'